# Node.JS Socket.IO SSL CORS error

Tags: node.js, sockets, ssl, cloudflare

So, I've made an app that makes use of NodeJS and Socket.IO and it worked fine. Recently, I've installed an SSL certificate and moved the socket from `http://example.com:8080` to `https://example.com:8443`. But now, I receive this error:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://example.com:8443/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=M4Kox0q. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
```

Now, I've made some research and I think it is because of the ports (request from `:443` to `:8443`), but how can I make it not be blocked?

This is the client-side code:

```
socket = io.connect("https://example.com:8443", {
    secure: true
});
```

And server-side:

```
io = require('socket.io');
server = require('https').createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync('./cloudflare.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./cloudflare.crt')
}, (req, res) => {
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    });
}).listen(socket_port);
io = io(server, {
    origins: 'example.com:*'
});
```

And, other than that, in the `Network` tab of the Dev Tools, the request is listed with a `523 No Reason Phrase` status code.

Other info that *may* be helpful:

- I use cloudflare SSL (using the `Full` option).
- I use NodeJS v9.4.0

Comment: You need to fix the cause of the 523 error. See http://getstatuscode.com/523 *“This status code is not specified in any RFCs, but is used by CloudFlare's reverse proxies to signal a resource that has been blocked by the administrator of the website or proxy itself”* and 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#523 *“Cloudflare could not reach the origin server; for example, if the DNS records for the origin server are incorrect”* and detailed explanation at https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200171946-Error-523-Origin-is-unreachable

Comment: I've read those materials before posting here, but, as I'm new to Cloudflare and HTTPS, they didn't help me solve it...

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle properly handle your CORS by installing [CORS](https://npmjs.org/package/cors) node package  with this simple configuration if using express.

```
const cors = require('cors')

let app = express()
app.use(cors({credentials: true, origin: true}))
```

OR

```
io = require('socket.io');
server = require('https').createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync('./cloudflare.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./cloudflare.crt')
}, (req, res) => {
    res.writeHead(200, {

    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"

    });
}).listen(socket_port);
io = io(server, {
    origins: 'example.com:*'
});
```

You can also checkout these sites [Enable CORS](https://enable-cors.org/server.html) or [MDN CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) handling.
I hope this help.

Comment: After doing the second suggestion, as I do not use Express, the error still persists. But, I don't know, here's an idea I had (but if true, I still need help solving it, as I'm new to Cloudflare and HTTPS). So, I took a look again at the **Network** tab again, and I saw that the request sent is of method `OPTIONS`. So, I don't know, maybe that's when my socket sends some options, including allowing CORS, but the reason behind the 523 error also blocks these options to be send. Actually, they never get to the server, as I tried a print in the console when they do and nothing happened,